# How does one define double-lines for edge and node shapes in graphviz dot?

Tags: diagram, graphviz, dot, entity-relationship

How can edges and nodes be styled using [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) [dot](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language) with doubled lines as shown the in the "LEGAL" and "TAX DISC" nodes of the following diagram?

[image: ER Diagram]

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Doubled shapes can be done by using `[peripheries=2]` on the node

Doubled edges can be done by specifying more than one colour for the edge, separated by a colon. In this case use the same colour twice: `[color="black:black"]` (or, to separate them slightly more, do `[color="black:invis:black"]`)

I got there eventually! Sorry for the "evolutionary" nature of this answer :-)

So for example

```
graph G {
    Foo [peripheries=2]
    Foo -- Bar [color="black:white:black"]
}
```

Comment: Using the color `white` with a non-white background or objects can cause problems.  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30759621/543738) for a better solution.

Answer (score 16):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6219948/543738) is correct about using the `peripheries` attribute for multiple node outlines.

However, using the color `white` to draw widely-separated double edges between nodes is not ideal.  If such an edge is drawn over a non-white background or crosses non-white objects, a white line will be visible.  It is much better to use one of the colors `none` or `invis`.  To update part of the example from the accepted answer:

```
graph G {
    Foo [peripheries = 2]
    Foo -- Bar [color = "black:invis:black"]
}
```

See the [Graphviz color documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/colors.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

(See other answers about normal edges and nodes)

The three color solution does not work with directed edges with `dir="back"`.

```
digraph A {
    foo -> bar [dir = "back", color = "black:invis:black"];
}
```

results in this output:

[image]

I tried wrapping it with `invis` layers outside. Looks a bit weird compared to normal arrows because of the increased edge width, but at least it is understandable to readers:

```
digraph A {
    foo -> bar [dir = "back", color = "invis:black:invis:black:invis"];
}
```

[image]

However this won't work with forward edges.